# How to skip lines of an ascii file beginning with special characters

Tags: python, ascii

I have an ascii file which contains lines beginning with

```
^[[1m
```

that I would like to skip.
I tried:

```
import re
f = open('MyFile.txt', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    if re.match(r'^[[1m',line):  
         continue
```

But I get an error message:

```
re_constants.error: unterminated character set at position 1
```

As suggested, I tried to use startswith but it doesn't match any line. Instead, escaping ^ and [ characters in the regex works.
I had misunderstood that using the raw option r would have make escaping social characters unnecessary. Thx !

Comment: Escape the backslashes or just use `startswith` instead of a regex.

Comment: `if line.startswith('^[[1m')`

Comment: Are the `^[` literal characters, or is that just how the single escape character (ASCII 27) is being displayed?

Answer (score 2):

The brackets are special char, and `^` too, you need to escape them to match the literal values

```
if re.match(r'\^\[\[1m', line):
```

Comment: Note that the raw string literal `r'...'` is used to prevent Python from recognizing escape sequences as part of the string literal. It doesn't do anything to prevent the regular-expression engine the *reads* the string from treating its own metacharacters specially.

Comment: Thx, https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner ! I completely missed this point !

Comment: @ciro to tag someone do `@chepner` in your message :)

Comment: @azro thx ! I was just looking hot to tag somebody !